# 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, postman, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to save my data to DB using Spring Restful web services.

I am continuously getting unsupported media type error when I run this code in Postman.

I have edited my code with front end JSP code and Repository class..

I have also added jackson dependency in pom.xml file. I am not able to figure out what's wrong with my code as I am a newbie towards Restful web services.

Controller::

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insp_rep/{id}",method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json" )
    ResponseEntity <Void> addRepo(@RequestBody PC_Repo report, @PathVariable("id") int id){
         this.pmService.addRep(report);
         return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

**JSP Code along with AngularJS script**

```
<html data-ng-app="formSubmit">
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('formSubmit', []);

    app.controller('FormSubmitController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.list = [];
            $scope.headerText = 'Inspection Report';

            $scope.submit = function() {

                var formData = {

                        "ins_id": $scope.ins_id,
                      "date_insp": $scope.date_insp,
                        "bedrooms":$scope.bedrooms,
                        "balcony":$scope.balcony,
                        "kitchen":$scope.kitchen,

                        "bath_toilet":$scope.bath_toilet,
                        "parking_gar":$scope.parking_gar,
                        "garden":$scope.garden,
                        "others":$scope.others,
                        "action":$scope.action

                };

                var response = $http.post('/PM/insp_rep/{id}', formData);
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.list.push(data);



                });
                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));

                });

                //Empty list data after process
                $scope.list = [];

            };
        }]);
</script>
```

**Repository Class**

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
@Table(name="abc")
public class abc implements Serializable {

    private java.sql.Date date_insp;
    private String bedrooms;
    private String balcony;
    private String kitchen;
    private String bath_toilet;
    private String parking_gar;
    private String garden;
    private String others;
        private String title;
private byte[]photo;
```

Comment: Problem is related with your request.It seems you are not sending request in proper json format.Check the dependencies like jackson present in classpath or not.

Comment: Hi Vaibs, thanks for your ans.. I have added dependency in pm.xml file. Please let me know if I have added a wrong dependency... The dependency I added is:   <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: it seems correct.check now

Comment: Hi Vaibs. I posted my front end JSP code embeded with angularjs code and repository class code, please let me know what wrong I have done with it..

Comment: Hello there, after going through your code i feel that you can easily pass form completely without writing so much lines. Please use 'ng-model' for fields of forms to be passed such as for bedroom <input ng-model="obj.bedroom" /> likewise for balcony <input ng-model="obj.balcony" />. Benefit of using this would be having jsonObject 'obj' ready to pass in controller having all the form values.

Answer (score 0):

As per explained above in the comments section, obj consists of all the form parameters submitted and passed to the controller.

**JSP HTML Tag:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.balcony" />
<input type"text" ng-model="obj.address" />
```

And in controller, try debugging the object value using alert and to convert the object in String use 'JSON.Stringify(obj)'.

**Controller JS:**

```
    $scope.submit = function() {
                 var formData = $scope.obj; 
                 alert(JSON.stringify($scope.obj));
                var response = $http.post('/PM/insp_rep/{id}', JSON.Stringify(obj));
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.list.push(data);
                });
                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
                });

                //Empty list data after process
                $scope.list = [];
            };
        }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I tried the code you have pasted above, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please add a snapshot of the post request from the console of the browser with proper request parameters. Inspect in the browser using developer console(Press F12 in the browser). I've edited the answer. Pass JSON.stringify(obj) in post request and post the error here with snapshot.